# The width of a list that contains an embedded matrix grows unexpectedly

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report in reporting services 2005 that includes a list with an embedded matrix and am attempting to put a border on the list, however, when I run the report in visual studio the matrix is growing past the end of the page and therefore the border is growing with it causing it to grow into the second page. It appears that there was supposedly a fix for this in reporting services 2000 service pack 1 but I am still experiencing the issue in 2005.

The list has a details group that limits the records on a row to 4 using the following expression: `=ceiling(rownumber("list1")/4)`, the matrix has a column group that should recycle those based on the rownumber determined by the list using the following expression: `=rowNumber("list1_Details_Group")`

I have also attempted to put the list in a rectangle in hopes to stop the matrix from growing to no avail.

How do I effectively stop the matrix form growing past the space allowed by the list control?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this....   the list was initially the width of the report which cause the boarder on it to grow that amount of space between the end of the matrix inside and the end of the list.  If I make the list the size of the matix that is embedded it will be the size of the matrix after it grows to accomodate the neccessay values.

In terms of the border, if you want the boarder of the list to line up with the width of the report a few things need to be done.  The size of the matrix columns that grow for each row must be exact where if there are 4 columns for each row the width of the matrix column is the width of the report / 4.  In addition you must always have 4 columns of data for each row in the matrix.  This can be accomplshed in the query by using the % (Mod) operator and adding additional records as needed.